# NoClassDefFoundError in google play ActionBarSherlock

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my project. When I open my project in emulator, it works
perfectly. However, when I upload the apk file on google play it gives me the following 
error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:343)
at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:162)
at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
at com.parkMe.ParkMyCarActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ParkMyCarActivity.java:180)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockActivity.java:184)
at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:60)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SherlockActivity.java:149)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2559)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:443)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:813)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:3128)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying to get an answer for 4 days. Please help!

Thanks
Cem Kacmaz